# How to go to the url return by a restful service as response

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am calling a java restful service in angularjs

```
  $http
  .post($scope.url,datatest)
  .success(function(data) {
    console.log('success');
 // console.log(data);
    $scope.responseURL=data;
    console.log($scope.responseURL);
  })
 .error(function(data) {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
```

Here the data is containing a url and I want to go to that url after success of service call.

Actually this is a transaction page where use will hit place Order button and then a service will be called which will return the url of payment getway.
Now I am supposed to redirect to that payment getway url.

Thanks

**Edit:**
Both the answer bellow are correct but the problem was, I was getting url as 'www.xyz.com/abc....' that's why it was being appended in the current url.

So I just prefixed the response url wiht 'http://' and it worked both way, the same tab and new tab as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Angular $window:

```
$window.location.href = $scope.responseURL;
```

Inject $window object in your controller function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`$location.path(url)`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location):

```
$location.path(data);
```

**Edit:** If you want to open it in another tab, you can try:

```
$window.open(data, '_blank');
```

---

*Note: Don't forget to inject `$location` in your controller.*

Comment: But the url contained in 'data' is being appended to the current page's url. I mean the url bar should only have the url contained in 'data' but it is something like 'current page's url/data"

Comment: Or how can I open it in another tab. I guess that will solve the problem of appending the new url in old one